# Birational morphism of the affine line

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Suppose $K$ has characteristic nonzero, can we characterize the birational morphism of $A^1$ the way we characterize isomorphisms(all linear maps)? I know it will not be as specific, but do we have any general ideas of what they are? For instance, is the Frobenius morphism birational? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Do you mean a regular map which is also birational, or a rational map (a regular map defined on an open dense subvariety) which is birational? 2. Do you know the characterization of birationality in terms of the function field?

Comment: @KReiser I meant a regular map that is also birational, so it is defined on the whole set. For your second question, do you mean the theorem saying that if we have a birational map(using your second definition. i.e. defined on subvariety) between X and Y, then k(X) isomorphic to k(Y)?

Comment: Yes, if a regular or rational map $X\to Y$ is birational, it induces an isomorphism of function fields. Can you calculate what the extension of function fields is and when it's an isomorphism in your case?

Comment: @KReiser In the case of $A^1$, the function field is simply $k(t)$. So $\phi$ is a birational morphism iff the induced map on $k(t)$, which should be defined by taking $f\in k(t)$ to $f\circ \phi$. Is this correct? So things like Frobenius would be birational since the induced map of $k(t)$ is taking $f(t)$ to $f(t^p)$, which has an inverse by taking $f(t)$ to $f(t^{-p})$.

Comment: The first two sentences are correct, but that's not an inverse (you have to send $t^p$ back to $t$, but $t$ is not a $p^{th}$ power in $k[t]$). I've written you an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can solve this is by recognizing that a morphism is a birational equivalence iff it is dominant and the induced extension of function fields is an isomorphism. Here, our morphism is given by $t\mapsto f(t)$ for some polynomial $f\in k[t]$, and this is dominant iff $f$ is nonconstant. The map on function fields is then $k(t) \to k(t)$ by $t\mapsto f(t)$.

To determine the degree of this field extension and whether it is an isomorphism, here is an elementary abstract algebra exercise: if $\varphi:k(t)\to k(t)$ is a homomorphism of fields, then it is of the form $t\mapsto \frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$ for polynomials $f,g$, and the degree of the field extension is $\max(\deg f,\max \deg g)$. In our case, $g=1$, so the degree of the field extension is $\deg f$, so our map is a birational map iff $f$ is a degree one polynomial in $t$.